# Cocos2d Sprite Sheet .plist doesn't link to correct texture file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

The following code doesn't seem to be working and I have looked all over to find different ways to do this but they all show it the same way.

```
+(CCActionAnimate*) initializeAnimation: (NSString*) animationName withNumFrames:(int)frames repeat:(bool)repeat withDelay:(float)delay;
{
CCAnimation *animation;

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", animationName];
NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:fileName];

NSMutableDictionary *framesDict = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]showSpriteFrames];

for(NSString *frameKey in framesDict)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", frameKey);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[framesDict objectForKey:frameKey] textureFilename]);
}

for(int i =1; i<=frames; i++)
{
   CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",animationName,i]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [frame textureFilename]);
    [animFrames addObject:frame];
}

if(repeat)
{
    for(int i = frames-1; i>=1; i--)
        [animFrames addObject:[[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png",animationName,i]] spriteFrame]];

}

animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames: animFrames delay:delay];


return [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
}
```

It seems to  find the proper .plist file but than does not connect to the correct texture even though in the .plist the target is correct. This is what I get in my NSLog when I try to run the game:

```
2014-07-16 15:19:37.604 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap4-hd.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.609 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.610 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap2-hd.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.615 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.617 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap1-hd.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.618 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.620 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap3-hd.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.621 Zipper[18602:60b] ZipperFlap.png
2014-07-16 15:19:37.623 Zipper[18602:60b] (null)
2014-07-16 15:19:37.625 Zipper[18602:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception      
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

It does not find the proper ZipperFlap-hd.png texture file even though it is clearly there and as I said it is listed as the .plist's target.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if anymore info is needed please let me know!

EDIT: I also just wanted to say that this was working properly until I recently cleaned my build. Now none of my animations work.

Comment: a problem occuring after cleaning build / deleting app from device indicates that your project does not contain the resource files referenced by code - it only continued to work because Xcode never removes resource files from an already deployed app bundle

Comment: I mean I checked under Build Phases in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' and it's all there. Is there somewhere else I should look?